# PDO prepared statement for updating record producing simple error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am extremely new to PHP. I'd like to use prepared PDO statements, but mine isn't working. [I tried to follow a simple example at](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html)

Here's what I have below(and yeah, I know range, range2, and spellrange all refer to the same thing, but I realized I got errors when I called the field in MySQL "range", so I changed the field to 'spellrange' in the database) - I did an echo of the POST stuff sent to the page (echo now removed), and I am getting all the POST information successfully - Here's the error:

> `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE id='747')' at line 2`

The id=747 is correct. That's the ID I clicked on from the previous page, and it does exist in the database. 
Hope I'm not too lame here, but I was trying to follow the example on that web site (which seemed like the simplest one I saw).

```
    <?PHP
// MAIN PROCESSING SECTION
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $level = $_POST['level'];
    $specialty = $_POST['specialty'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $cost = $_POST['cost'];
    $bcu = $_POST['bcu'];
    $range2 = $_POST['range'];
    $prereq = $_POST['prereq'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

try {
$sql = "UPDATE tblspells 
    SET level=?, specialty=?, name=?, cost=?, spellrange=?, basecostuses=?,  prereq=?, description=?) WHERE id=?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($level, $specialty, $name, $cost, $range2, $bcu, $prereq, $description, $id));
}
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error ---------- " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have two `)` in your query for no reason - start by removing those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for starter, You have extra closing brackets after `'description'` and `where` clause.

Comment: Yeah, caught that 10 seconds after posting :(. I fixed that so now it is: ...prereq=?, description=? WHERE id=?)    Still got the error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2

Comment: Didn't think the feedback would be this fast on a Sunday night!

Comment: Yes, you need to remove both closing brackets, since you dont have an opening bracket in the sql statement.

Comment: Ouch! Total newbie typos!!!. Left over from when I was trying something else I am sure - I need to go to sleep. Works fine now. THANKS! - I would up vote your answer, but I need to have a 15 reputation :)